# PDO Execute Statement Times Out

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I am having quite some trouble and am unable to find the source of the problem but I cannot send a simple update to my sqlite3 database which simply times out and doesn't do anything. It said thirty seconds at first but then I changed it to 5 minutes and it still wouldn't do anything to query through a simple 1 rowed sqlite table.

```
  if (isset($_POST['apply']))
    {
    try {
    $bio = $_POST['bio'];
        $file_db = new PDO('sqlite:Secure/data.sqlite');
        // Set errormode to exceptions
        //$file_db->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8"); 
        $file_db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, 
                            PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        //
        echo("$bio $name");

        $sql = "UPDATE `users`
        SET `profile` = :bio
        WHERE `name` = :name
        ";
        echo("2");
        $statement = $file_db->prepare($sql);
        echo("3");
         $statement->bindValue(":bio", $bio);
         echo("4");
        $statement->bindValue(":name", $name);
        echo("5");
        $statement->execute();
        echo("6");


          $file_db = null;        // Disconnect
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
        //$statement->bindValue(":profile", $profile);
        //$statement->execute();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears there was a variable being set in template.php called result, no idea why but I set this to null and all worked well...

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from your `bindValue()` call:

```
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':bio', $_POST['bio'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindValue(':name', $_POST['name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();
```

or

```
$statement = $db->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array(':bio' => $_POST['bio'],':name'=>$_POST['name']));
```

When doing updates, it is a good idea to check if it actually affected a row

```
if($statement->execute()){
   echo 'success !';
   if($statement->rowCount()>0){
     echo 'record updated !';
   }else{
     echo 'no record updated !';
   }
}else{
   echo 'failed !';
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66561/discussion-on-answer-by-meda-pdo-execute-statement-times-out).